# stored procedure in mysql to make a select with variable params

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem with a stored procedure in MySQL. I need to call it from a PHP code (I can't use the select straight from the code). The procedure receive the parameters from a form, and that parameters could be a string or numeric value (if the user fills the input) o a null (if the user left the input blank).

I made this code, but it doesn't work (procedure and variable names are in Spanish) and it didn't show any error.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE ps_BusquedaVarParam
    (IN nombre varchar(30), apellidos varchar(50), minEdad int, maxEdad int)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE 
(nombre is null or Nombre = nombre) and 
(apellidos is null or Apellido = apellidos) and 
(minEdad is null or Edad>=minEdad) and 
(maxEdad is null or Edad<=maxEdad);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: MySQL didn't show any error, but the procedure don't return the correct data. If a send as values a name (nombre) that is stored in the table and three null the procedure shows a empty table instead of the correct row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE ps_BusquedaVarParam(nombre_in varchar(30), apellidos_in varchar(50), minEdad_in int, maxEdad_in int)
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE 
(nombre_in is null or Nombre = nombre_in) 
and (apellidos_in is null or Apellido = apellidos_in) 
and (minEdad_in is null or Edad>=minEdad_in) 
and (maxEdad_in is null or Edad<=maxEdad_in);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I suppose the problem was in the name of the variables, because was the same as the field names starting with lower case.

Comment: @DonnieRock Please accept the answer, it's the usual way to say thanks here and to signal others that the issue is already solved. See how it works [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)